# Can I "hide" anything defined in a header file in C++

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

Let's say I Have a header file `test.h`.

```cpp
#pragma once

extern uint64_t a;

void foo( uint64_t );
```

In my case, `uint64_t` is used to represent a [Bitboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitboard) as a part of my chess engine
 `test.h` 
 Naturally I will be using `uint64_t` everywhere. I wanted to create a type alias for `uint64_t`, as `Bitboard`. 
So I did

```cpp
using uint64_t = Bitboard;
```

But since this is a header file, `Bitboard` is now defined everywhere, since this header file is used by almost all the other files of the project. 
**The problem is that I only want to use this alias in `test.h`.**

### The problem

The project isn't small, and `Bitboard` isn't a very unique identifier, I feel a global alias like this **can** cause some collisions, and hence I want to strictly keep it within `test.h`.

Is there any way I can still use create something in a header file, and not have it leak into all the other files of my project?

Comment: You say this causes a problem, but you haven't really said what the problem is.  I don't see why it should be a problem.  Anyway, you could use namespaces.  I also suggest you use `typedef` instead of `using`.  A question to ask yourself is _why_ this header is used by all the rest of your project.  Maybe you have an organizational problem.

Comment: @paddy I recently got criticized for using `typedef`, and not `using`.  I have organized functions into namespaces, but I do want something like a type alias to be only visible in the source of my header file and not any other file that might use it! I will edit the question and explain the issue.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What about the source files where you implement the functions declared to use this type? Should they still use `uint64_t`? Or what about the code calling these functions using variables?

Comment: What is the reason you want to "hide" this type outside the header file? Wha problem is that supposed to solve? Right now this is really too much of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: You tell us you want to solve an unknown problem, which makes it hard. If you tell us about the underlying problem you want to solve, we could then maybe provide solutions that maybe you haven't thought of. Always tell us the real problem you need to solve.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I hope the question is clear now, I have stated the problem clearly. It *is* a problem for me.

Comment: I have doubts about your need for such a thing, but if you really can justify doing something so offbeat, it's solved trivially with "ugly C" #define, #ifdef, and #undef.

Comment: @CareyGregory It's not solved completely because if any other file in same translation unit also defines the macro - without undefining - then you have a name collision on re-definition.

Comment: Regarding name collisions, since youre programming in C++, the natural solution would be to use namespaces. Or encapsulate your code in classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best you can do is use an ugly C `#define`

```
#pragma once

#define Bitboard uint64_t

extern Bitboard a;
void foo(Bitboard);

...

#undef Bitboard
```

Comment: This is very useful, may I ask why you would consider this to be "Ugly"?

Comment: If you want ideas for a simple chess engine you can look at [my own](https://github.com/ktsiam/GoodKnight)(shameless plug). It's pretty simple and concise.

Comment: @AryanParekh `#define` statements literally string-replace text before the compiler runs, so this can sometimes cause unexpected problems. If you use it on a small context and then use `#undef` it's usually ok.

Comment: I have been working on this one for a while now, Bitboards is the only real challenge, then comes the evaluation.

Comment: @AryanParekh. That's true. But evaluation is boring, so why not just do the fun part?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can still use create something in a header file, and not have it leak into all the other files of my project?

No. Included files are included entirely. If an included file contains something, then that something will be included. Simple solution is to not put something into the header that you don't want it to contain.

---

> ```
> using uint64_t = Bitboard;
> ```
>
> But since this is a header file, Bitboard is now defined everywhere

That doesn't define `Bitboard`. That defines `uint64_t` - which is an identifier reserved to the language implementation in the global namespace.

---

> The project isn't small, and `Bitboard` isn't a very unique identifier

Besides the solution of not defining it mentioned above, a way to deal with this is to define the name within a namespace so that its uniqueness improves.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! That is exactly what my problem is though.

Comment: @AryanParekh The solution to the problem is to remove the thing from the header that you want to not be included.

Answer (score 1):

Move it into a new header file, one that will be included only by the source files you want privy to the secret.